# Update Database Form: leaves image fields blank when no file is selected

Tags: php, mysql, database, file, upload

i'm creating a content management system so that the database can easily be updated. i've created an update page that lets the user edit entries in the database, and they can upload new images and edit any of the fields without any problems.
the problem i have, is that if you just want to edit, say just the text in one field, but you don't want to change the images, when the form is submitted, it overwrites the image field with a blank entry.
what i want to be able to do is for the original image to remain if no other file is selected.
i know that i need to check if a file has been selected but i can't seem to find a way of doing it that works. i'm sure it's probably something simple, but here's the script i have for the upload:

```
     $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
/* upload image script */

$thumb=basename($_FILES['thumb']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'],"../shopImages/".$thumb))

$image1=basename($_FILES['image_1']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_1']['tmp_name'],"../shopImages/".$image1))

$image2=basename($_FILES['image_2']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_2']['tmp_name'],"../shopImages/".$image2))

/*end of script*/
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}


if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
 $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE tbl_products SET thumb=%s, image_1=%s, image_2=%s, title=%s, `desc`=%s, category_id=%s, status=%s, shipping_band=%s, price=%s WHERE product_id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($thumb, "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($image1, "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($image2, "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['title'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['desc'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['category_id'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['status'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['shipping_band'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['price'], "double"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['product_id'], "int"));
```

here is the code for the form:

```
<form method="post" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
       <td nowrap align="right">Product ID:</td>
      <td>

    <?php echo $row_RS_updateProducts['product_id']?>

  </td>
<tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap align="right">Thumb:</td>
  <td><?php echo $row_RS_updateProducts['thumb']?><input type="file" name="thumb" value="<?php echo $row_RS_updateProducts['thumb']?>" size="32"></td>

</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap align="right">Image 1:</td>
  <td><?php echo $row_RS_updateProducts['image_1']?><input type="file" name="image_1" value="<?php echo $row_RS_updateProducts['image_1']?>" size="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap align="right">Image 2:</td>
  <td><?php echo $row_RS_updateProducts['image_2']?><input type="file" name="image_2" value="<?php echo $row_RS_updateProducts['image_2']?>" size="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap align="right">Title:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_RS_updateProducts['title'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap align="right">Description:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="desc" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_RS_updateProducts['desc'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap align="right">Category:</td>
  <td><select name="category_id">
    <?php 
do {  
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_RS_Category['category_id']?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_RS_Category['category_id'], htmlentities($row_RS_updateProducts['category_id'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>><?php echo $row_RS_Category['category_name']?></option>
    <?php
} while ($row_RS_Category = mysql_fetch_assoc($RS_Category));
?>
  </select></td>
<tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap align="right">Status:</td>
  <td><select name="status">
    <option value="1" <?php if (!(strcmp(1, htmlentities($row_RS_updateProducts['status'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Available</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if (!(strcmp(2, htmlentities($row_RS_updateProducts['status'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Pending</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if (!(strcmp(3, htmlentities($row_RS_updateProducts['status'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Unavailable</option>
  </select></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap align="right">Shipping Band:</td>
  <td><select name="shipping_band">
    <option value="a" <?php if (!(strcmp("a", htmlentities($row_RS_updateProducts['shipping_band'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>A</option>
    <option value="b" <?php if (!(strcmp("b", htmlentities($row_RS_updateProducts['shipping_band'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>B</option>
    <option value="c" <?php if (!(strcmp("c", htmlentities($row_RS_updateProducts['shipping_band'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>C</option>
    <option value="d" <?php if (!(strcmp("d", htmlentities($row_RS_updateProducts['shipping_band'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>D</option>
  </select></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap align="right">Price:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_RS_updateProducts['price'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Update record"></td>
</tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1">
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $row_RS_updateProducts['product_id']; ?>">
</form>
```

i'm new to php so any help would be much appreciated as i've been stuck on this for days now.

Comment: can anybody help me on this? i'm new to php and really stuck on it. i've tried all the suggestions in the comments but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

have you mentioned in your form

```
<form name="form_name" action="actionpage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

if you have not written enctype="multipart/form-data" your file will not be uploaded.

Comment: yes, i have that. the file upload works fine. it's when i don't want to update the images that is the problem. as the form stands, i have to upload the images again each time i want to update any other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Check the $_FILES components before doing the move files logic

Like this:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['thumb']['name'])){
   $thumb = basename( $_FILES['thumb']['name'] );
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'],"../shopImages/".$thumb);
}
if(!empty($_FILES['image_1']['name'])){
   $image1 = basename( $_FILES['image_1']['name'] );
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_1']['tmp_name'],"../shopImages/".$image1);
}
if(!empty($_FILES['image_2']['name'])){
   $image2 = basename( $_FILES['image_2']['name'] );
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_2']['tmp_name'],"../shopImages/".$image2);
}
```

And Change your query to look like this:

```
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE tbl_products SET title=%s, `desc`=%s, category_id=%s, status=%s, shipping_band=%s, price=%s ",
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['title'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['desc'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['category_id'], "int"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['status'], "int"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['shipping_band'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['price'], "double"));

if(isset($thumb)){
  $updateSql .= sprintf(" thumb=%s", GetSQLValueString($thumb, "text"));
}

if(isset($image1)){
  $updateSql .= sprintf(" image_1=%s", GetSQLValueString($image1, "text"));
}

if(isset($image2)){
  $updateSql .= sprintf(" image_2=%s", GetSQLValueString($image2, "text"));
}

$updateSql .= sprintf(" WHERE product_id=%s", GetSQLValueString($_POST['product_id'], "int"));
```

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply. i had tried that method before and could get it to work. i have just tried it again as you suggested but still no joy.

Comment: What does this return?
    GetSQLValueString($thumb, "text"),

That may be inserting void blank in your query with the sprintf

Comment: if i upload an image, that will insert the path for the thumbnail into the database field and upload the image file to the correct folder. if i don't browse for the file when simply updating the database, then it will overwrite the previously uploaded image with a blank entry.

Comment: So you can change your query to update only when it has a value, or make $thumb, $image1 and $image2 be the current value if there is no new one.

Comment: i can change the image, but it if don't change it, it will be blank. i want it to work so that it keeps the current value if i don't change the image file.

Comment: I was just telling what you can do, but I see you won't do it yourself, check my edited answer.

Comment: i just edited it as you suggested but that stops the upload from working. i still need to be able to upload images using the form in case the image needs to be changed, but if no image is selected, it need to remain as the current file.

Comment: please can you help? i'm really stuck on this one.